# Custom Groovy function with arguments doesn't work in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using a function to set environment variables in Jenkins pipeline. I've noticed that if I declare function without argument, it works, but if I declare function that accepts 1 string argument, Jenkins throws error `No such DSL method 'get_metadata' found among steps` while running my pipeline.

```
def get_metadata(String type) {
    switch(type) {
      case "env":
        return "environment name";
        break;
      case "domain":
        return "domain name";
        break;
      case "cloud":
        return "cloud name";
        break;
      default:
        return "none";
        break;
    }
}

pipeline {
  environment {
    PROJECT=get_metadata()
    CLOUD=get_metadata(type: "cloud")
    DOMAIN=get_metadata(type: "domain")
    ENVIRONMENT=get_metadata(type: "env")
  }
}
```

Function without argument works when I call it like `get_metadata()`

```
def get_metadata() {
<...>
}
```

Jenkins version is 2.289.2.

Comment: Your `get_metadata` does not define a default value for `type` and therefore the call to `PROJECT=get_metadata()` throws an error, as you can't use it as is without the `type` parameter.

Comment: @NoamHelmer That is the correct answer, so you may want to convert comment into answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_metadata` does not define a default value for type and therefore the call to `PROJECT=get_metadata()` throws an error, as you can't use it as is without passing the `type` parameter.

To solve it you can just add a default value to your function:

```
def get_metadata(String type = '') {
   switch(type) {
     case "env":
        return "environment name";
     case "domain":
        return "domain name";
     case "cloud":
        return "cloud name";
     default:
        return "none";
   }
}
```